# Cannot reach port of gcloud appengine devserver

Tags: bash, gcloud, devserver

for testing I try to run the gcloud devserver inside docker with that comment:

```
sudo /usr/local/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/java_dev_appserver.sh --disable_update_check --port=8888 --help /app/target/qdacity-war/ 2>&1 | sudo tee /app/logs/devserver.log > /dev/null &
```

To check if the devserver has started successfully, I use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This script waits until the port 8888 is open.

SERVER=localhost
PORT=8888

TIMEOUT=180
TIME_INTERVAL=2

PORT_OPEN=1
PORT_CLOSED=0

time=0
isPortOpen=0

while [ $time -lt $TIMEOUT ] && [ $isPortOpen -eq $PORT_CLOSED ];
do 

    # Connect to the port
    (echo > /dev/tcp/$SERVER/$PORT) >/dev/null 2>&1
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        isPortOpen=$PORT_CLOSED
    else
        isPortOpen=$PORT_OPEN
    fi

    time=$(($time+$TIME_INTERVAL))
    sleep $TIME_INTERVAL
done

if [ $isPortOpen -eq $PORT_OPEN ]; then
    echo "Port is open after ${time} seconds."

    # Give the server more time to properly start
    sleep 10
else
    echo "Reached the timeout (${TIMEOUT} seconds). The port ${SERVER}:${PORT} is not available."

    exit 1
fi
```

After running all the test, I just got back:

```
Reached the timeout (180 seconds). The port localhost:8888 is not available.
```

I couldn't find out if there were any problems starting the devserver or querying the port.
Does anyone have an idea or solution?
Thanks!

Comment: What is the output of `lsof -i :8888`? That should give your the process ID (PID) of any process that is currently listening on that port.

Comment: Have you tried to run your app server using other port?

Comment: @Gerb Thanks, I used "sudo lsof -i :8888" but I don't get any output, no table or error :/

Comment: @AndresS Thanks, but changing the port leads to the same result.

Answer (score 0):

By default, by only accepting localhost|loopback traffic, you're unable to access the server remotely.

Please try adding `--address=0.0.0.0`:
([link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server#command-line-arguments)) to your `java_dev_appserver.sh` command.

#### Example

Used a variant of Google's [HelloWorld](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/appengine-standard-java8/helloworld) sample.

Ran this with `mvn appengine:run` (to confirm it works and build the WAR).

Then `/path/to/bin/java_dev_appserver.sh ./target/hellofreddie-0.1` (to confirm it works with the local development server).

Then used Google's Cloud SDK container image ([link](https://hub.docker.com/r/google/cloud-sdk/)), mounted the previously generated WAR directory into it, and ran the server on `:9999`:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive \
--tty \
--publish=9999:9999 \
--volume=${PWD}/target:/target \
google/cloud-sdk \
  /usr/lib/google-cloud-sdk/bin/java_dev_appserver.sh \
  --address=0.0.0.0 \
  --port=9999 \
  ./target/hellofreddie-0.1
```

Am able to curl the endpoint:

```sh
curl \
--silent \
--location \
--write-out "%{http_code}" \
--output /dev/null \
localhost:9999
```

returns `200`

And, running your scripts adjusted with `PORT=9999` returns:

```sh
Port is open after 2 seconds.
```

Comment: I used a simple HelloFreddie example, generated a WAR (directory) and ran `java_dev_appserver.sh --address=0.0.0.0 --port=9999 ./target/hellofreddie-0.1` within `docker run --interactive --tty --publish=9999:9999 --volume=${PWD}/target:/target google/cloud-sdk` and am able to curl the endpoint as expected. So, this appears to work for me for the simple case running the app inside a docker container.